# Using gradient displays for histograms in r

Tags: r, plot, gradient, histogram

I have a dataset (n = 9,141,954) that looks like this

```
data<-c(rep(1, times=401),rep(2,times=443789),rep(3,times=5276376),rep    (4,times=3003895),rep(5,times=404108),rep(6,times=13181),rep(7,times=205))
```

Which as a histogram looks like this:

```
hist(data,prob=T,breaks=5)
```

From left to right, i want to display the colours "darkgreen" "chartreuse4" "yellowgreen" "yellow" "orange2" "red" and "red3"

Which I know i can do using col=c("darkgreen","chartreuse4", ....etc), but what I would like to do is display these colours as a gradient across the histogram, weighted by the relative contribution of each of the values to the dataset. For example, value = 1 makes up only 0.004% of the cell values (401/9141954*100), and value = 4 makes up 32.9% of the data. Therefore, I would like the gradient display to have 0.004% assoicated with "darkgreen" but 32.9% associated with "yellow", and so on for the rest of the values/colours.

Does anyone know how this can be done???

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
res <- hist(data,breaks=5)
plot(res)

cols <-c("darkgreen","chartreuse4","yellowgreen","yellow","orange2","red","red3")
colcombos <- data.frame(embed(cols,2)[,2:1],nums=round(res$density*600))
selcols <- unlist(
             apply(colcombos,1,function(x) colorRampPalette(c(x[1],x[2]))(x[3]))
           )

dens <- 100
bar.dens <- 1/100

rect(
 seq(1,7-bar.dens,bar.dens),
 0,
 seq(1+bar.dens,7,bar.dens),
 rep(res$counts,each=dens),
 col=selcols,
 border=NA
)

plot(res,add=TRUE)
```

Result, which doesn't look that exciting unfortunately, but the colours are there, if you plot barplots all of a uniform height:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi. Thanks for replying. But i am after gradient shading across the bins, from green through yellow orange to red, with the proportion of "darkgreen" displayed aligning to the value 1...through to the amount of red3 aligning to the amount of value 7. Sorry if my explanation wasnt clear before! Im not sure how to create gradient shading, similar to grey scale displaying from black to white???

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Wouldn't that just be achievable using `hist(..., col=c("darkgreen","charteuse4", etc etc))`. Can you mock up an example and post it to imgur.com or somewhere similar?

Comment: Hi again. Sorry (new to R and stack exchange!) I am trying to display more than one colour within a bin. The example above has 4 bins, and I want to display 7 colours shaded across from left to right, similar to a rainbow display often used on 3D contour plots. I note one of your answers to a previous post, which seems similar (gradient of n colours from col=c(red,blue)) using colorRampPalette. But the key difference is that I want to display more than one colour within a histogram bin i.e. seven colours shaded across 4 or 5 bins....

Comment: @user3229751 - i've had another go - see what you think.

Comment: That looks fantastic! Thanks. One last thing - is there any way to display the colour gradient unevenly, depending on the original dataset. For example, only 401 values in the dataset equalled 1, but 5276376 values equalled 3. If darkgreen represents value 1, and yellow green represents value 3, can we shade the gradient proportionally? i.e. hardly any (<1%) dark green and a lot (~57%) of yellow green??

Comment: Hi @thelatemail I am applying your script to another dataset, and I cannot work out how to correct the offset....data<-c(rep(0, times=90),rep(2,times=1179),rep(3,times=1212420),rep (3, times=3047410), rep(5,times=546307), rep(6,times=44558), rep(7,times=376)). Please assist! I feel like it is in the rect( section but cannot work out how to fix it.